# What am I getting wrong in this Jquery code, wishing to select an element where attribute is equal to particular value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wish to just select and place border around
`.L1Cell` element where attribute name `parent` equals
to `Workstaion`. However it's selecting all `.L1Cell` elements it seems.

Here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WNnLQ/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

          var firstLevel = $('#MenuContainer').find('.FirstLevel').attr('parentname','Desktop-Mobile'); 

    firstLevel.find('.L1Cell').attr('catname','Workstation').css('border','3px solid black');


alert('running');

    });
```

Comment: attr (2 arguments) sets something, it is no condition

Comment: you could use ECMAScript 1.6 Array.filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. You would have to access it like so

```
firstLevel.find('.L1Cell[catname="Workstation"]').css(...)
```

You are simply setting **every attribute** to Workstation and adding `.css()` . Because .attr() is here to retrieve data from certain attributes and to set certain values for attributes. Not for searching something !

Some documentation on .attr():

- http://api.jquery.com/attr/

The right thing you are looking for is an Attribute Selector, documentation goes here:

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/